# Expression must be a modifiable lValue: `(x, y) = 0;`

Tags: c++, arrays

I have a template class Array which implements a 2 dimensional array. The array class contains an overloaded operator () which returns a reference to the element at the zero-based position (column x, row y):

```
const T & operator () (int x, int y) const {
        size_t loc = y*width + x;
        return *(buffer + loc);
    }
```

I also have a derived class image which represents a generic data container for a ppm image.The image class contains a setPixel method which sets the RGB values for an (x,y) pixel:

```
void setPixel(unsigned int x, unsigned int y) {     
            size_t locpixel = y*width + x;
            size_t componentofpixel = locpixel * 3;
            (x, y) = 0;
            (x, y) + 1 = 1;
            (x, y) + 2 = 0;
    }
```

So when I compile it shows an error in setPixel that the expression must be a modifiable lValue. Is there any way to use the operator () in my setPixel method to take the next element on the array?

Comment: Do you expect `(x, y)` to be calling your `operator ()`?

Comment: Thats what I am trying to do

Comment: You need an instance to call the operator on.  try `(*this)(x, y) ...`

Answer (score 0):

Unlike a member function a operator needs to have an instance in order to be used.  Right now when you do `(x, y)` you call the comma operator and the compiler evaluates the expression `x`, discards it and then evaluates the expression `y` and returns what that yields.  That return is a temporary value and you cannot assign to it since it is a built int type.

In order to call the function call operator you need to give it an instance to call it on.  In this case you can use

```
(*this)(x, y) = 0;
(*this)(x, y) + 1 = 1;
(*this)(x, y) + 2 = 0;
```

This now gets resolved to calling the `operator()` you have defined for type.